# Lost control with \marginpar

Tags: margins, marginpar

I want to include marginal notes *only on the left side* of a large document.  (For your information, I have included all the packages listed in the preamble of the document in the following minimal example. The `marginnote` package was added in vein to fix this problem.)

**Constraint:** I cannot change the `\documentclass`.

I lost control with the `\reversemarginpar` in the second page of this minimal document.

Is there a quick fix to this problem?

**Edit:** After reading the comments, I may have to pay attention to what page I am in (even or odd) while typing margin notes.  Is it possible to add some sort of a `\newcommand` so that I do not have to do this? Otherwise, it is going to be a very time consuming project.

```
\documentclass[11pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    
\usepackage{caption,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[perpage,para,symbol*]{footmisc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 1}}
%I want the margin note to appear on left.  Hence the reason to use \reversemarginpar
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 2}} 
%I still want the margin note to appear on left. But it isn't.
\lipsum[2]\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 3}}
%ISo I tried \reversemarginpar again.  but, \reversemarginpar does not work anymore.
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `oneside` option to the `\documentclass`? I mean `\documentclass[11pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}`.

Comment: If the above isn't an option, you can use `\normalmarginpar\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 2}}` in even pages (`marginnote` is not needed in any case). If you want I'll make an answer with different possibilities.

Comment: @karlkoeller: I have to check and see if oneside can be used. Please make an answer.  I would appreciate it.

Comment: I tried \normalmarginpar (it works with the minimal example) but it does not in the main document. I will try to see if I can adjust the minimal document to reflect the problem.  I am wondering if any of the packages is interfering. (oneside option can be used but has no effect.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your document doesn't need to be two-sided, you can simply load the `amsart` class with the option `oneside` and issue a global `\reversemarginpar` at the beginning of the document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 1}}
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 2}}
\lipsum[2-3]\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 3}}
\lipsum[3-5]\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 4}}
\end{document}
```

If the above is not an option, i.e. your document needs to be two-sided, you can define a new command `\mymarginpar` which checks whether the page is odd or even and use this one instead of `\marginpar`

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \reversemarginpar%
    \marginpar{#1}%
  \else%
    \normalmarginpar%
    \marginpar{#1}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\mymarginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 1}}
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[1]\mymarginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 2}}
\lipsum[2-3]\mymarginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 3}}
\lipsum[3-5]\mymarginpar{\textcolor{red}{ID 4}}
\end{document}
```

Note that, if you still want to use `\marginpar`, you can adopt the trick

```
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \reversemarginpar%
    \oldmarginpar{#1}%
  \else%
    \normalmarginpar%
    \oldmarginpar{#1}%
  \fi%
}
```

The result is, in any case:

[image]

P.S. I've removed all unnecessary packages from the preamble (including `marginnote`).

Comment: Your second answer worked beautifully in my case.  Thank you.